# Node.js driver "mongodb" implementation of findAndModify() - how to specify fields?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, node-mongodb-native

I'm trying to pop and retrieve an element out of an array stored in a document. I can't use $pop since it doesn't return the POPed element. I'm trying to use findAndModify() instead. It works in the shell console, but I'm having troubles getting it to work using the mongodb node.js driver (https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongodb).

my document structure looks like so:

```
{ _id: '1', queue: [1,2,3]}
```

In mongo shell, I do:

```
> db.collection.findAndModify({ query: { _id: 1 },
                                update: { $pop: { queue: -1 } },
                                fields: { queue: { $slice: 1 } }, new: false })
```

$slice ensures that the returning document shows the element that has just been poped. To clarify, I'm not interested in what is in the queue, I'm only interested in what I have just popped out of the queue.

returns:

```
< {_id: 1, "queue": [1]} // yes, it works!
```

Using the mongodb library, I don't know how to specify the $slice: 1, it doesn't seem to be supported in the options(?):

```
> db.collection('collection').findAndModify(
        { _id: 1 },
        [],
        { $pop: { queue: -1 }, queue: { $slice: 1 } },
        { new: false },
        function(error, results) {
           if(error) {
              console.log(error);
           }
           console.log(results);
        }
);
```

returns:

```
< MongoError: exception: Field name duplication not allowed with modifiers
```

Basically - where should I put the "queue: {$slice: 1}" part in the nodejs query to make this work? Is it even supported in the node.js driver implementation?

Also, it doesn't seem like findAndModify() is meant to be used this way. If $pop was returning the POPed value, it would be ideal. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks, 
 - Samir

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that the node.js implementation does not support the 'fields' operand at all.

We've figured out this work around:

1) We store each element in it's own document, instead of an array within the same document.

2) Now findAndModify works like so:

```
db.collection('collection').findAndModify(
        {}, // findAndModify will match it to the first document, if multiple docs are found
        [],
        {},
        {remove: true, new: false }, // returns & removes document from collection
        function(error, results) {
           if(error) {
              console.log(error);
           }
           console.log(results);
        }
);
```

Some good links that helped us and might help you if you have a similar issue:
https://blog.serverdensity.com/queueing-mongodb-using-mongodb/
http://www.slideshare.net/mongodb/mongodb-as-message-queue